# 16.04/16.10/17.04: Cannot get rid of laptop screen flickering

Tags: drivers, unity, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I'm frustrated. Whatever I try, I cannot get rid of the screen flickering reported by many other users, too. 
I have a GeForce GTX 1050 Ti. Laptop was preinstalled with Ubuntu 16.04 and everything worked fine for a few weeks. Then I guess related to a system update my laptop screen started with this annoying flickering. Since then I've tried a lot:

- install latest nvidia drivers
- remove all nvidia drivers and try nouveau
- switch between Intel GPU and GeForce
- try settings in Nvidia Settings Manager like high performance mode
- ping graphic card with nvidia-settings -q all in a loop
- upgrade to 16.10 and then 17.04, install latest drivers
- reinstall ubuntu-desktop, xorg, xserver-xorg
- CCSM Workarounds
- some xorg settings I've found along the way

After upgrading to 17.04 and reinstalling ubuntu-desktop it worked for 1 day. I was able to turn my laptop screen to full brightness, unplug my laptop from power and still no flickering (this causes heavy flickering normally). I'm not sure why it worked the one day even after shutdown. Then the next day the flickering was back without any setting changes or new updates. I just turned on my laptop in the morning and boom, same story again.

Some observations:
When I turn down brightness of the laptop screen, flickering frequency is lower and I'm able to work at the screen somehow, but it is very dark and every now and then flickering comes back.

The only thing that really works is an external monitor. I turn off laptop display then but that's no real solution because I need to be able to work mobile.

In full brightness mode:
Login screen does not have the flickering issue, but immediately after login it starts. When opening the launcher (pressing windows key) the flickering stops. Hiding launcher -> flickering continues

Looking at all this I'd say there must be a solution. I'm not sure what causes the problems Unity, Nvidia card, ... But why does flickering stop when launcher is open? And can I set my system into that state permanently? Any ideas? Is there a better place to ask that question?

Best regards,
Alex